# Excel pivot tables sum if a condition is met

Tags: excel, if-statement, conditional-statements, pivot-table

I have an excel table that looks something like this

```
Queue   Duration(in seconds) Language
a            310                FR
a            342                EN
b            220                FR
a            654                FR
c            340                EN
c            157                EN
a            163                FR
b            713                EN
b            436                FR
b            185                EN
c            264                FR
a            365                EN
```

i would like a table that looks like this

```
Queue    Total Duration          Total Duration
         of English calls        of French Calls
a             707                   1127
b             898                   656
c             497                   264
```

I can use a filter in a pivot table and manually create my table but this didn't seem like an elegant solution. And my actual table is 47 columns and 170,000 rows. I tried using a calculated field but I couldn't figure out how to sum if the language field met a certain criterion.

I can also use the language field in the rows but then I get separate lines for French and English and I cannot compare them in charts and graphs.

I would appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: Just use `Language` as the columns field and use the filter to keep only EN and FR.

Comment: Thanks for the response. The only valid entries in the Language field is En and Fr so I don't need to filter for them. If I use Language in the columns field I get something like this

FR 2047
EN 2102


However, that doesn't help me because I need the counts by queue. If I include queues in the columns, I get all the numbers I need but not in a format that makes it easy to chart or do further analysis.

Comment: And you have Queue in the Rows field?

Comment: No the Queues is in the column filed because I need to aggregate all my numbers by Queues.

Comment: Try putting it in the rows field. It will aggregate.

Comment: Sorry. Queues is in the rows field. It does aggregate and gives me all the numbers I want but it gives me separate rows for the English Queues and the French queues. I would like them in the same row because I need to compare the two. I only included call duration in this sample, but I have quite a few other fields where I need to compare the French and the English queue numbers. So it would help if there is a way to get them on the same row. Is the output table I provided above at all possible with pivot tables?

Comment: [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vkb1s.png) is the pivot table I get with the data provided. I'm not sure why it's not working for you.

Comment: I'm so sorry. I had my language in Values not in columns. The solution did work for me. Thank you so much.